# Converting audio and video into mp4 format

Tags: c

I am  converting audio and video into mp4 format but when there is a resolution change in video it is showing error so if there is a multiple resolution in a video can't we convert that to mp4 format. If it is possible then tell me how to that plz

Answer (score 0):

Convert the video to another format first, one that allows you to convert videos of different resolution to a single video with a single resolution, then convert that video to mp4 format. What software are you using for the conversion?